# Is there a way to get the server ID of the registered server in an Azure storage sync service through power shell or ARM template?

Tags: powershell, server, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-files

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "serverLocalPath": "string",
    "cloudTiering": "string",
    "volumeFreeSpacePercent": "integer",
    "tierFilesOlderThanDays": "integer",
    "friendlyName": "string",
    "serverResourceId": "string",
    "offlineDataTransfer": "string",
    "offlineDataTransferShareName": "string"
  }
}
```

What needs to be passed as a server resource id in the above template format for storage sync. How do we get the server id ?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use the [Get-AzStorageSyncServerEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storagesync/get-azstoragesyncserverendpoint?view=azps-5.5.0) cmdlet from the [Az.StorageSync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storagesync/?view=azps-5.5.0) module to list all server endpoints within a given sync group.

```
Get-AzStorageSyncServerEndpoint -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -StorageSyncServiceName "mysyncservice" -SyncGroupName "testsyncgroup"
```

Sample Response:

```
SyncGroupName                               : testsyncgroup
StorageSyncServiceName                      : mysyncservice
ServerLocalPath                             : C:\Users\onpremwindows\Desktop\myfolder
ServerResourceId                            : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.stor
                                              agesync/storageSyncServices/mysyncservice/registeredServers/8ec8b78c-0739-195r-856e-2e7r5ta2c13w
ServerEndpointName                          : 94e9fd59-23d6-9854-99c1-3e9a8ab73760
ProvisioningState                           : Succeeded
LastWorkflowId                              : storageSyncServices/mysyncservice/workflows/bd3o8c77-7183-4a46-8830-9b156dd2f011
LastOperationName                           : ICreateServerEndpointWorkflow
FriendlyName                                : onpremwindows
SyncStatus                                  : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.StorageSync.Models.PSServerEndpointHealth
CloudTiering                                : Off
VolumeFreeSpacePercent                      : 20
TierFilesOlderThanDays                      :
OfflineDataTransfer                         : Off
OfflineDataTransferShareName                :
OfflineDataTransferStorageAccountResourceId :
OfflineDataTransferStorageAccountTenantId   :
InitialDownloadPolicy                       : NamespaceThenModifiedFiles
LocalCacheMode                              : UpdateLocallyCachedFiles
ResourceId                                  : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.stor
                                              agesync/storageSyncServices/mysyncservice/syncGroups/testsyncgroup/serverEndpoints/94e9fd59-23d6-9854-99c1-3e9a8ab73760
ResourceGroupName                           : myResourceGroup
Type                                        : microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints
```

`8ec8b78c-0739-195r-856e-2e7r5ta2c13w` would be the ServerId you can pass.

You can obtain the ServerId using the [Get-AzStorageSyncService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storagesync/get-azstoragesyncservice?view=azps-5.5.0) cmdlet as well:

```
Get-AzStorageSyncService -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -StorageSyncServiceName "mysyncservice"
```

Sample response:

```
StorageSyncServiceName    : mysyncservice
ServerName                : 8ec8b78c-0739-195r-856e-2e7r5ta2c13w
ServerCertificate         :
AgentVersion              : 8.0.0.0
ServerOSVersion           : 10.0.14393.0
ServerManagementErrorCode : 0
LastHeartBeat             : 12/10/2019 12:55:01
ProvisioningState         : Succeeded
ServerRole                : Standalone
ClusterId                 : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ClusterName               :
ServerId                  : 8ec8b78c-0739-195r-856e-2e7r5ta2c13w
StorageSyncServiceUid     : 76104503-6cd8-4812-7884-c4288e87a8cd
LastWorkflowId            : storageSyncServices/finalsync/workflows/0e3bc737-7619-4b42-81a9-aec36e3fbf53
LastOperationName         : ICreateRegisteredServerWorkflow
DiscoveryEndpointUri      : https://tm-server.xxx.com:443
ResourceLocation          : eastasia
ServiceLocation           : eastasia
FriendlyName              : onpremwindows
ManagementEndpointUri     : https://tm-server.xxx.com:443
MonitoringEndpointUri     : https://tm-server.xxx.com:443
ResourceId                : /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/mysyncservice/registeredServers/8ec8b78c-0739-195r-856e-2e7r5ta2c13w
ResourceGroupName         : myResourceGroup
Type                      : microsoft.storagesync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers
```